# Vulkan vkCreateImage: The combination of format, type, tiling, usage and flags (...) unsupported when creating depth image

Tags: vulkan, multiview

I'm trying to create an offscreen renderpass, but error append before the offscreen stuff, when I create the depth image.
I took the prepareOffscreen() fonction from Sascha Willems https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/offscreen/offscreen.cpp
I had to adapt it from C++ to C, and add the multiview support.
The ovrVkRenderPass argument is only here to retreive compatible color and depth format.

I 've got the message from the validation layers:

```
Error: [Validation] Code 180358038 (...) 
vkCreateImage: The combination of format, type, tiling, usage and flags supplied in the VkImageCreateInfo struct is reported by vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties() as unsupported.
```

But I can't find my error.

```
// Framebuffer for offscreen rendering
typedef struct {
    VkImage image;
    VkDeviceMemory mem;
    VkImageView view;
} FrameBufferAttachment;

typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    VkFramebuffer frameBuffer;
    FrameBufferAttachment color;
    FrameBufferAttachment depth;
    VkRenderPass renderPass;
    VkSampler sampler;
    VkDescriptorImageInfo descriptor;
} OffscreenPass;

OffscreenPass offscreenPass;

static void prepareOffscreen( ovrVkRenderPass * renderPass )
{
    // Setup the offscreen framebuffer for rendering the menu texture
    // The color attachment of this framebuffer will then be used to sample from in the fragment shader of the final pass
    offscreenPass.width = 640;
    offscreenPass.height = 480;

    int layerCount = vk.isMultiview ? 2 : 1;
    const int faceCount = 1;
    const int arrayLayerCount = faceCount * MAX( layerCount, 1 );

    // Color attachment
    VkImageCreateInfo image;
    image.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    image.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    image.format = renderPass->internalColorFormat;
    image.extent.width = offscreenPass.width;
    image.extent.height = offscreenPass.height;
    image.extent.depth = 1;
    image.mipLevels = 1;
    image.arrayLayers = arrayLayerCount;
    image.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    image.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
    // We will sample directly from the color attachment
    image.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;
    image.pNext = NULL;
    image.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    //image.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;
    //image.pQueueFamilyIndices = NULL;
    image.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo memAlloc;
    memAlloc.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    VkMemoryRequirements memReqs;

    VK( vkDevice->vkCreateImage( vkDevice->device, &image, VK_ALLOCATOR, &offscreenPass.color.image ) );
    VC( vkDevice->vkGetImageMemoryRequirements( vkDevice->device, offscreenPass.color.image, &memReqs ) );
    memAlloc.allocationSize = memReqs.size;
    memAlloc.memoryTypeIndex = VkGetMemoryTypeIndex( vkDevice, memReqs.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT );
    VK( vkDevice->vkAllocateMemory( vkDevice->device, &memAlloc, VK_ALLOCATOR, &offscreenPass.color.mem ) );
    VK( vkDevice->vkBindImageMemory( vkDevice->device, offscreenPass.color.image, offscreenPass.color.mem, 0 ) );

    VkImageViewCreateInfo colorImageView;
    colorImageView.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    colorImageView.pNext = NULL;
    colorImageView.flags = 0;
    colorImageView.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
    colorImageView.format = renderPass->internalColorFormat;
    colorImageView.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    colorImageView.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    colorImageView.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    colorImageView.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0; // .baseArrayLayer = 1 is giving a Validation error, don't know why
    colorImageView.subresourceRange.layerCount = layerCount;
    colorImageView.components.r = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_R;
    colorImageView.components.g = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_G;
    colorImageView.components.b = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_B;
    colorImageView.components.a = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_A;
    colorImageView.image = offscreenPass.color.image;
    VK( vkDevice->vkCreateImageView( vkDevice->device, &colorImageView, VK_ALLOCATOR, &offscreenPass.color.view ) );

    // Create sampler to sample from the attachment in the fragment shader
    VkSamplerCreateInfo samplerInfo;
    samplerInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_CREATE_INFO;
    samplerInfo.magFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    samplerInfo.minFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    samplerInfo.mipmapMode = VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_LINEAR;
    samplerInfo.addressModeU = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
    samplerInfo.addressModeV = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
    samplerInfo.addressModeW = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
    samplerInfo.mipLodBias = 0.0f;
    samplerInfo.maxAnisotropy = 1.0f;
    samplerInfo.minLod = 0.0f;
    samplerInfo.maxLod = 1.0f;
    samplerInfo.borderColor = VK_BORDER_COLOR_FLOAT_OPAQUE_WHITE;
    samplerInfo.pNext = NULL;
    samplerInfo.anisotropyEnable = VK_FALSE;
    samplerInfo.unnormalizedCoordinates = VK_FALSE;
    samplerInfo.compareEnable = VK_FALSE;
    //samplerInfo.compareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_NEVER;
    VK( vkDevice->vkCreateSampler( vkDevice->device, &samplerInfo, VK_ALLOCATOR, &offscreenPass.sampler ) );

    // Depth stencil attachment
    image.format = renderPass->depthFormat;
    image.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT;

    VK( vkDevice->vkCreateImage( vkDevice->device, &image, VK_ALLOCATOR, &offscreenPass.depth.image ) );        // this last call to vkCreateImage trhow the error:
The combination of format, type, tiling, usage and flags supplied in the VkImageCreateInfo struct is reported by vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties() as unsupported.

    (...)
}
```

Comment: "*I can't find my error.*" Your error is in the part of your code where you ask the implementation if it is valid to create an image with that format/etc.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, can you be more explicit please?

Comment: Before creating an image, you are supposed to have asked the implementation if it will *allow* you to create an image with the format/etc that you're using (or you're using a combination of things that the specification guarantees is supported). This is what your error is saying: the implementation doesn't allow you to use that combination of format, tiling, etc. So, where did you get permission to create images with that specific combination of stuff? Or if you're using spec guarantees, where does the specification guarantee that this combination is supported?

Comment: Ok, thx for your help.   The creation of the color image doesn't trigger error, why the depth image creation does? As you can see I only changed format and usage, and the format came from a valid renderpass. (Leave a response, so that I can validate it.)

Comment: "*As you can see I only changed format and usage*" "only"? Why do you think that this is somehow immaterial? I don't know how to say it any more plainly than I did: "Before creating an image, you are supposed to have asked the implementation if it will allow you to create an image with the format/etc that you're using (or you're using a combination of things that the specification guarantees is supported)." This is *not optional*.

Comment: Transform your comment into an answer, i can then accept it. Thx again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicol Bolas helped me find the problem. I now use the format returned by this vr_api function:

```
static VkFormat ovrGpuDepthBuffer_InternalSurfaceDepthFormat( const ovrSurfaceDepthFormat depthFormat )
{
return  ( ( depthFormat == OVR_SURFACE_DEPTH_FORMAT_D16 ) ? VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM :
        ( ( depthFormat == OVR_SURFACE_DEPTH_FORMAT_D24 ) ? VK_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT :
        VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED ) );
}
```

I wonder why these vr_api enums are not directly correlated with Vulkan enums.

Comment: Nicol Bolas doesn't post an answer, so I accept my own answer in order to close this question.